# 'Always Run Asynchronously' option in developer console returning 10000ms CPU time limit

Tags: apex, governorlimits, asynchronous

Running a test class via developer console in sandbox with 'Always Run Asynchronously' option checked. Why does Limits.getLimitCpuTime() return 10000ms in this context and not 60000ms?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Operations that don’t consume application server CPU time aren’t counted toward CPU time.**

CPU time is calculated for all executions occurring in the transaction—for the executing **Apex code**, and any processes that are called from your code, such as package code, workflows and validation rules.

CPU time is private for a transaction and is isolated from other transactions.
**The code has to be executed in a Queueable context and a Batch context or any other async method( @future)**

Tests run asynchronously, but it's not really async method - so the limit here is 10,000 milli seconds.